# Custom Django Login

Tags: python, html, django

I'm struggling to pass through/access the password that should be passed through from the form I have created. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I need a custom login page since I want to alter the way the username is inputted. I've changed my username authentication just for the time being to try and get this standard version correct before I change my username verification back.

**html Login template**

[image]

I want the password input to be visible to the user

**Views.py**

[image]

The prints return 'None' on the console

**urls.py**

[image]

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong or advise if this is a terrible way to create a custom login page on Django

Comment: You are missing the `name` attributes for your `input` tags.

Comment: @Selcuk <3 Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add name attributes to  tags

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27801378)

Comment: It wouldn't let me accept a comment as an answer, so i added it below @user2339071

Comment: Yes, yes it does, I was missing the name attribute from my form inputs. The form now works. Question solved